# How to extract values from a file using pattern(s) from a column in another file, and insert such values as a new column to the latter?

Tags: shell-script

I sample "winning" sets of 60 game cards such as [this one](http://sales.starcitygames.com//deckdatabase/displaydeck.php?DeckID=72098) and extract the card *names* and *count* and format it for use with some software. The output *format* is:

> .<ID><tab>*count*<tab>*name*

*Step 1*

I start with the text version of the set using the [link](http://sales.starcitygames.com//deckdatabase/deck_files/72098-MODO.txt) provided on the page(next to *print*) and keep the data(2 columns separated by a space) removing the *Sideboard* cards.

*Step 2*

For each card name, I search a local `list` file containing a list of cards properties separated by semicolons and match the card name on the second field to extract the first field which is the *ID number* for the corresponding card(lines were shortened here as only the first fields matter):

```
ID;Full Name;...
0;Air Elemental;1;Air Elemental;0800h;;;;;;;
1;Ancestral Recall;1;Ancestral Recall;0800h;;;;;;;;
2;Animate Artifact;1;Animate Artifact;0800h;;;;;;;
...    
10780;Jace, the Mind Sculptor;1;Jace, the Mind Sculptor;0008h;;;;;;;;
10871;Aura Finesse;0;Aura Finesse;0008h;;;;;;;
```

...I then prefix each line from *step 1* with *.ID*, making sure the 3 columns are separated with a tabulation. The final *output* file looks like this(I'm not concerned with the header part):

```
;MY1 - Shardless BUG - #1
;
;User
;User E-Mail
;28/08/2014
;1
;4th Edition
;

.12516  2   Baleful Strix
.12533  4   Shardless Agent
.12700  4   Deathrite Shaman
.9038   4   Tarmogoyf
.10780  2   Jace, the Mind Sculptor
.12004  2   Liliana of the Veil
.12     2   Bayou
.10747  2   Creeping Tar Pit
.12645  4   Abrupt Decay
.1547   4   Brainstorm
.2285   3   Force of Will
.1456   1   Hymn to Tourach
.13650  1   Toxic Deluge
.9286   3   Thoughtseize
.239    1   Swamp
.1486   4   Polluted Delta
.258    3   Underground Sea
.10706  4   Verdant Catacombs
.3329   2   Wasteland
.1      4   Ancestral Recall
.10612  2   Misty Rainforest
.252    2   Tropical Island
```

Considering the aforementioned source *text* file and the `list` file, how can produce the output file with the required *format*?

Comment: This is really a programming problem of the kind that for which most shell dialects are *not* suited. I suggest you look at using Python or some similar such scripting language with which you're familiar. And if you still need help with that go to stackoverflow because this is a programming problem not a Unix one.

Comment: while it is technically possible to do this with a shell-script this is the kind of task that is far from easy to achieve using that. I think your own answer below actually illustrates rather well that the kind of code you'll end up getting in shell-script does not express the intent of your code very well. In fact your problem description reads a lot like an SQL query joining two tables.

The reason I suggested Python ("or some similar such scripting language") was that it's easy to perform small text-processing tasks in that, as well as perform cross-table matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did is that I trimmed the `list` file down to the first two values (ID;Name), then I used this script on the source text [file](http://sales.starcitygames.com//deckdatabase/deck_files/72098-MODO.txt):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dos2unix "$1"
sed -e '/Sideboard/,$d' "$1" -e '/^$/,$d' | tee source_strip | cut -d ' ' -f 2- >temp
while IFS= read f; do
  sed -n "s/\([0-9]*\);$f$/\.\1/p" list
done <temp >IDs
sed -ni 's/^\([0-9]*\) \([a-zA-Z]*\)/\1\t\2/p' source_strip
paste IDs source_strip > final
cat final
```

Of course this assumes an *ID number* exists for every name search otherwise this won't properly work. Surely there is more elegant way to do this, but in this case it does work!

Comment: I should have removed the _IDs_, _temp_, and _source_strip_ temporary files at the end of the script. Also using `unix2dos` on the _final_ file if I'm going to use this in Win. The script doesn't always work with a quote in the name when searching the _list_ file. Either not quoting the variable properly or dos control chars in the list file. But it helps!